# JS round value to 2 decimal places within a message/pop up

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a project and found an error with a JS message in the UI. The number is not being rounded before being displayed. I don't know JS very well however, I did try `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` this did not work.

Any support with this would be great.

```js
  if ($change_return_val != "0.00") {
  // confirm('Oops amount is over.');
  // calculate_balance_due();
    swal({
        title: "Change: £" + $change_return_val,
        text: "Your change return value is: £" + $change_return_val,

    })
  }
```

[Change return message in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG1bp.png)

Comment: Try `parseFloat($change_return_val).toFixed(2)` this will fix the value to 2 decimal places

Comment: Hi @Ameer, Like this: title: "Chnage £"+parseFloat($change_return_val).toFixed(2),

Comment: Exactly @LewisB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting a `number` to a `string` with a specified number of floating points, as @Ameer has said in a comment the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function is the typical way to go. However, for the specific task of displaying a `number` as currency, you may want to consider using [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) instead.

For example, this converts the number into British English style, specifically as the currency of Great British Pounds:

```js
const numberRaw = 123.456789;
const numberCurrency = numberRaw.toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });

console.log(numberCurrency);
```

This method is also particularly useful if you have to deal with many locales, some of which may display numbers in quite different ways such as `'1.234,57'`.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you very much for your answer. tolocalstring works very well for me. Ameer's comment also works.